# I should have sued, had I not been forced to formally resign

Tags: termination

This is an odd work story from two years ago.

I live in the suburbs in Indiana, and had just gotten a new job working in Chicago.

I took the train to work, like many people living in the same area, and the commute was roughly an hour and a half (one way), including the quarter mile walk from the train station to the office.

They wanted me to be in the office from 8 to 5, sharp, without missing a beat (they even complained if I took 30 minutes for lunch).

I worked my butt off as a software engineer at this place and provided code that everyone on the team was impressed with.

I was new to public transportation and it was flu season, so I ended up taking two sick days in a row.

Upon coming back to work, I was called to a meeting with the CEO and CTO.

The CEO told me that he was worried about me making the long commute, and with my "flu and all" he didn't think it was going to work out.

He said that I could sign a "formal letter of resignation and receive a months pay in advance" (I had only been there four weeks) or he could "fire me on the spot."

I, having a five month old son at the time, agreed to the formal letter of resignation and signed.

Of course, I had a terrible time finding a job.

For one, it was the winter months.
Two, no one believed my story.
Two companies that I interviewed with told me that they thought my story was bullshit and that "no one gives a fired employee a month of pay."

To top it off, my son got bronchitis shortly after I was fired and we didn't have medical coverage.
I tried to fight them for COBRA, but they were very quick to get a lawyer involved who claimed that they were not required to provide me coverage through COBRA for some reason.

I don't want to press charges now, but I have always wondered if I should have pressed charges then.

Did I throw away my chances of pressing charges by signing the formal letter of resignation. Could I have ever pressed charges.

Comment: What charges do you think could be “pressed”? Had you qualified for the employers group plan during your four weeks with the employer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about legal advice and as such should either be directed to a lawyer or asked on the Law Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Moo idk, charges? Pressing them? Charges you can press? Some sort of compensation for apparent wrong doing against me? I realize now how uneducated this post was, but I was a member of the group plan before my termination.

Comment: @Moo I am unfamiliar with Law Stack Overflow, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: “Charges” are typically criminal in nature and only some jurisdictions provide for private prosecution, so you need to be clear as to what action you think you can take here - for civil matters, you sue, which involves a complaint that the other side has to answer in court.  There may be a labour issue here which a labour body in your jurisdiction might be able to take criminal action over, but that would require legal advice.  Did you pay any COBRA related insurance premiums after your termination?  It’s not free, you still have to make premium payments, and your employer must be eligible.

Comment: @Moo solid info! Thank you! As I said, I'm not trying to actually do anything now. Just was curious. But thank you from all of the future readers.

Comment: IANAL but 2 years is not that long ago and you *might* still have some avenue for legal redress. Best course of action would be to contact a lawyer who specializes in employment law. They'll be able to tell you what your options are (or were).

Comment: "Two companies that I interviewed with told me that they thought my story was bullshit..." - Next time do not share the details of your story here in an interview. Focus on your value to the new company and when it comes to the old company just stick to the fact that you resigned.

Comment: The fact that a minor has no medical coverage depending on their parents income is not a workplace issue, that's a glaring issue with your political system. I will never understand why a leading industry nation values freedom so much that they chose the freedom to deny children healthcare because it has a smell of "socialism" if every child could just be properly cared for.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not omitting information and I have emails between the CEO and I that prove I was denied coverage through COBRA. I left out that I, luckily, managed to find a new job just before there would have been a lapse in coverage for my child. Had there been, I would have been required to apply for unemployment and government or private insurance, which is where I was concerned that resigning would affect me. I am no expert on this matter, so the downvotes do not help. They only discourage users from looking to the community for answers. Thank you for your "expertise."

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You also threw away your right to unemployment.  *Or thought you did*, that was the real point of it (for them).

Actually, when you are "asked" to resign (or else you'll be fired), unemployment works same as if you *were* fired - there's a hearing, and you get the unemployment unless the employer can show you engaged in serious misconduct.

Rejecting you from COBRA, however, was a real dick move.  You bear the cost of COBRA, so it was no skin off his nose.  Your state probably has an ObamaCare-derived insurance program which is **income**-based, so they don't look at assets.  There are also programs specifically to ensure children are covered.